# Reference parameter lifetime

Tags: c++, object-lifetime

Given the following:

```
class ParamClass {...};

class MyObject {
public:
    void myMethod(ParamClass const& param) { _myPrivate = param; }

private:
    ParamClass _myPrivate;
}

[...]

MyObject obj;

void some_function(void)
{
    ParamClass p(...);
    obj.myMethod(p);
}
```

What will happen to _myPrivate at the end of the lifetime of object p?
EDIT: will I still be able to use _myPrivate to access a copy of object p?

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121781/assigning-value-passed-by-reference-to-a-member-variable-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `_myPrivate` is **not** a reference, in the assignment `_myPrivate = param`, its value will be copied over from whatever the reference `param` points to, which in this case is the local variable `p` in `some_function()`.

So *if the assignment operator for `ParamClass` is implemented correctly*, the code should be fine.

> will I still be able to use _myPrivate to access a copy of object p?

With the above caveat, yes. But to be precise, `_myPrivate` can not be used to *access* a copy of `p`; it *is* a variable containing a copy of the data in (the now extinct) `p`.

Answer (score 0):

in `myMethod` you invoke the assignment operator of `ParamClass` which by default makes a bitwise copy of the object (you can define your own operator). So you create a copy of p, which will be accessible

Comment: it makes a member-by-member copy, not a bitwise copy

Answer (score 0):

A reference is like an alias to an object. The reference has no lifetime of its own. The lifetime to consider is the lifetime of the object referenced.

In your example, _myPrivate is an object so the operator= will copy the reference-passed objet p. p will be destroyed, and the parameter reference will reference nothing, but _myPrivate, as a copy will be OK.

It would be a problem if _myPrivate was declared as :

```
ParamObject& _myPrivate;
```

In this case, you end up with a "dangled" reference : Undefined behavior :)

my2c

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

`_myPrivate = param;`

In this statement assignment operator (`ParamClass::operator=`) copies values of each member of the object referred by `param` into members of `_myPrivate`. When `some_function` returns, `p` is moved from stack - it disappears. But `_myPrivate` now contains copies of `p`'s members' values.

If `ParamClass` has members that are pointers to dynamically allocated memory, you must make sure that `ParamClass::operator=` performs *deep copy*, otherwise you might have problems with dangling pointers - `ParamClass`'s destructor might free that memory but `_myPrivate` will have a member that still points to it!